# XPath Classic ASP

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic, vbscript

Obviously I'd much rather batter the person who decided that spitting out xml like the following was a good idea, but alas, I can't. ;-)

I have the following xml:

```
<search>
    <key_0>
        <ContentTitle>blah</ContentTitle>
    </key_0>
    <key_1>
        <ContentTitle>blah blah</ContentTitle>
    </key_1>
</search>
```

What would be the correct xpath to get the data out.
If, as it should, the node names were 'key' each time, the following asp, with the xpath of //search/key would do the job perfectly. However, I can't work out the correct xpath / way of doing this, or how to modify the code otherwise.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

```
Dim mydoc : Set mydoc=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
mydoc.async=false
mydoc.loadXML(xmlFile)

If mydoc.parseError.errorcode<>0 then
    Response.write mydoc.parseError.errorcode & " is the error code!<br />"
Else
    Set xmlPNode = mydoc.selectNodes("//search/key")

    If(xmlPNode.Length=0) Then
        response.write "No results found!"
    Else
        Dim iTotalResults : iTotalResults = (xmlPNode.Length - 1)
        Dim i
        For i = 0 to  iTotalResults
            strContentTitle=GetXMLItem("ContentTitle", i)
        Next
End If
Set xmlPNode = Nothing
End if


Function GetXMLItem(strpItem, ipValue)
    Dim nlOutput : Set nlOutput = xmlPNode(ipValue).selectNodes(strpItem) 
    If(nlOutput.Length<>0) Then
        GetXMLItem=nlOutput(0).Text
    Else
        GetXMLItem=""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sometimes if you've got the task of processing poorly designed XML the best thing is to start by transforming it (using XSLT) into better XML. That way, the task of dealing with the badness only has to be done once.

Comment: This seems to be the right way around it. So thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should set SelectionLanguage property to XPath or use a specific version of MSXML which uses XPath as its default selection language.
 More information : [SelectionLanguage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
The query you should use to get nodes whose name starts with "key_" : 
 `search/*[starts-with(name(), 'key_')]`
A test script that based on your xml document, consider.

```vb
Dim xmlFile
    xmlFile = "<search><key_0><ContentTitle>blah</ContentTitle></key_0>" & _
    "<key_1><ContentTitle>blah blah</ContentTitle></key_1></search>"
Dim mydoc 
Set mydoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0") 'by default selection language is XPath
    'mydoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    mydoc.async=false
    mydoc.loadXML xmlFile
If mydoc.parseError.errorcode <> 0 Then
    Response.Write mydoc.parseError.errorcode & " is the error code!<br />"
Else
    Dim xmlPNode
    Set xmlPNode = mydoc.selectNodes("search/*[starts-with(name(), 'key_')]/ContentTitle")
    If xmlPNode.Length = 0 Then Response.Write "No results found!"
    Dim nodeTitle
    For Each nodeTitle In xmlPNode
        Response.Write nodeTitle.parentNode.nodeName & " : "& nodeTitle.nodeTypedValue & "<br />"
    Next
    Set xmlPNode = Nothing
End If
Set mydoc = Nothing
```

Comment: Changing to MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0 gives:

Do not use CreateObject to create XML DOMDocument or XMLServerHTTP objects, instead use Server.CreateXMLObject and Server.CreateXMLHTTPObject

However I haven't found this error message or any mentions of CreateXMLObject or CreateXMLHTTPObject in regards to ASP, but only Javascript.

Changing CreateObject to CreateXMLObject gives me the error of
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Server.CreateXMLObject'

Unfortunately using that xpath with XMLDOM tells me no results found.

Comment: I'm setting this to be the correct answer, as using this xpath, with the idea of using xslt by @MichaelKay, is everything I need.